# c# detect when number has changed and do behaviour

Tags: c#

I have a specific behaviour that I need to detect.

A timer (polling an API) is constantly checking a variable. The variable will be between 0 and 1.
It normally sits at either 0 OR 1.
But when it changes between the value, it takes a few seconds and exposes the numbers in between, for example when it goes from 0 to 1, it goes 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 etc over a few seconds, then will stay at 1 for a while, before it goes back down to 0 gradually some point later.

Basically what I need to do, is when if the number has been 0, when it goes above 0, for example 0.1, I need to act like it is already 1, as I cannot wait for it to be 1.
The same applies if its 1, then starts to go down to 0, I need it to act like 0 as soon as it starts to go down.

My starting code is:

```
 if (value == 0)
     //Do 0 task
 else if (value == 1)
     //Do 1 task
```

I can solve it going upwards, for example:

```
if (value == 0)
     //Do 0 task
 else if (value > 0.1)
     //Do 1 task
```

But of course that wont work going downwards.

Im trying to work out logic where it stores the previous number and detects change in either direction but cant get my head round it.

Comment: What's going to be changing the variable? If you control access to the variable, then you can put logic in the code that updates the variable to check it. You need to describe the situation better in your question.

Comment: Yes perhaps its hard to describe. I am basically a polling an API with the timer, and reading the variable from there. So cannot control the variable.

Comment: You're making a ramp detector.  Similar idea to a "peak detector".  I suggest reading some of the existing explanation of peak detectors.

Comment: As one example of Mason's idea, can you add a property as a layer of abstraction and read that instead of the variable itself? Record which direction it is moving when it is set? Then on get, it would return the proper value.

Comment: `/* assume start at zero */ while(true) { while(value == 0) task0; while(value != 1) task1; while(value ==1) task 1; while(value != 0) task0; }` This assumes that the value always changes from 0 to 1 and back, and never returns to 0 before reaching 1 and vice versa.

Comment: Perhaps off-topic, and not the smallest of changes, but this sounds like a job for SignalR. That way you can avoid the polling and you can instead broadcast a notification to the client(s) as soon as the changes you want to look for are detected on the server(!) side.

Comment: @PeterB If only I had control of the API. Its only 15 years old ;)

Comment: are you storing the previous value? if so you can just check if value > or < previous value.   if  (value < prevValue)  { prevValue = 0; //Do 0 task } else if (value > prevValue) { prevValue = 1; //Do 1 task

Comment: @JamieD77: No, that won't work at all.  You have to store `prevValue = value;`, otherwise the ramps will be turned into oscillations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hardest part is that when the value is not 0 neither 1, you need te determine which direction it was going.

I would solve it with a statemachine, because you have two states. Going up or going down. So you need two parts of code. Ofcourse you could solve this by using a boolean, because there are only two cases, but I'd rather use this. easier to set breakpoints etc.

It looks a bit like this: *(wrote this directly here, so may contain typo's)*

```
// love readable switches, so I use an enum.
enum Direction
{
    Up,
    Down,
}

private Direction _direction = Direction.Up;
private Direction _currentState = Direction.Down;

void Update()
{
    // which mode are we in? Going up or going down.
    switch(_direction)
    {
        case Direction.Up:
            // we were going up, but we reached 1, so the next would be 
            // going down.
            if(value == 1)
            {
                // change direction
                _direction = Direction.Down;
                break;
            }
            
            // if the value is higher than 0 and the currentState was down
            // execute the task and set the currentState on up
            // this way we execute the task ones
            if(value > 0 && _currentState == Direction.Down)
            {
                // run task 0
                _currentState = Direction.Up;
            }                


            break;

        case Direction.Down:
            // were going down, if the value is zero, we change direction.
            if(value == 0)
            {
                // change direction
                _direction = Direction.Up;
                break;
            }

            // if the value is smaller than 1, it's moving down.
            // if the currentstate was up, it is now going down.
            // this way we execute the task ones
            if(value < 1 && _currentState == Direction.Up)
            {
                // run task 1
                _currentState = Direction.Down;
            }                
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this one worked best for my scenario.

Comment: I'm not sure this handles the case well when the value sits at 0 or 1 for a while: You switch the direction as soon as it gets there, but what is actually wanted is to continue the behavior (= stay in this state, I think) until the value *leaves* 0 or 1. E.g. v==0: task0() v=0: task0(); v=0.1: task1(); v=0.5: task1(); **v=1: task1(); v=1: task1();** v=0.9: task0(); v=0.1; task0(); v=0: task0();  v=0: task0();  v=0.2: task1(); etc.

Comment: I partially agree, maybe the choice of variable name is a bit poor.
The `direction` variable is mainly to check whether we should check whether we go from 0 to 1 or from 1 back to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply add an additional *else* to recognize increasing or decreasing numbers:

```
if (value == 0)
{
    // Do 0 task
}
else if (value == 1)
{
    // Do 1 task
}
else
{
    if (previousValue > value)
    {
        // Do 0 task
    }
    else
    {
        // Do 1 task
    }
}
previousValue = value;
```

Comment: This doesn't correctly handle two consecutive equal values during a ramp.  Other than that it's simple and doesn't suffer from problems of other suggested solutions.